# Turning a shape made by a bezier path into a SKNode while maintain attributes such as color and gradients

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, sprite-kit

I know with SKShapeNode you can set its shape to a bezier path, however is there a way to transfer the bezier path "as is" with all the colors into a SKNode?

For example, I have this code for a shape:

```
//// General Declarations
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Color Declarations
UIColor* fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.333 green: 0.333 blue: 0.333 alpha: 1];
UIColor* strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 1];

//// Gradient Declarations
NSArray* gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    (id)fillColor.CGColor, 
    (id)strokeColor.CGColor, nil];
CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(-0.5, 51.54)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(209.94, 51.54)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(198.28, 88.97)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(357.67, 90.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(358.25, 51.54)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(480.5, 56.92)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(480.5, 0.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(-0.5, 0.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(-0.5, 51.54)];
[bezierPath closePath];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[bezierPath addClip];
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(240, 90.5), CGPointMake(240, 0.5), 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
[strokeColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];


//// Cleanup
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

This code when drawn on the screen makes a shape that looks like this:

[image: Shape]

Is there a way I can turn this shape into a SKNode while maintaining the color and gradient? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of SKShapeNode is a subclass of SKNode, so everything you can do with an SKNode you can do with a SKShapeNode.

An SKNode is not "displayable". It's a holder for other nodes which can be rendered like SKShapeNode and SKSpriteNode. If you want a SKSpriteNode from your SKShapeNode you can use SKView's [textureFromNode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/textureFromNode%3a) and thus obtaining a SKTexture which you can use to initialise a SKSpriteNode.